# ggplot display Pareto front only for the points that belong to a specific level

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, pareto-chart, pareto-optimality

Libraries being used

```
install.packages("rPref")
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("igraph")
install.packages("ggplot")
```

Taking `mtcars` dataset from R as an example.

In order to find the Pareto frontier and level value one establish the preferences

```
p <- high(mpg) * high(hp)
```

Then calculate the level-value w.r.t. p by using top-all

```
res <- psel(mtcars, p, top = nrow(mtcars))
```

When one creates the visualization as follows

```
gp <- ggplot(res, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = factor(.level))) + geom_point(size = 3)
```

It will show a plot with the mpg and hp values of mtcars with colors, and each of the color represents the level (proximity to optimum). As follows

[image]

If one wants to plot the Pareto front line for every area of all points of a lower level, one can run

```
gp + geom_step(direction = "vh")
```

That results in

[image]

However, as for one's case only the 1st level is relevant, how does one display only the dots and the specific pareto front for level 1?

Changing the `factor(.level)` to `factor(1)` as

```
gp <- ggplot(res, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = factor(1))) + geom_point(size = 3)
```

Gives the following, which is ignoring the previous levels but some that would not belong to Level 1 seem to be featured in it

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
data(mtcars)
p <- high(mtcars$mpg) * high(mtcars$hp) 

res <- psel(mtcars, p, top = nrow(mtcars))
res1 <- res %>% filter(.level == "1")
gp <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = res, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = factor(.level)), size = 3) + 
  geom_step(data = res1 , aes(x=mpg, y=hp, color=factor(.level)))
```

[image]

---

### Edit to resolve comments

Here's the same graph without the other points:

```
res %>% filter(.level == "1") %>% 
  ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = hp), size = 3) + 
    geom_step(aes(x=mpg, y=hp))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, however without showing the points that belong to levels that are not the first one. And, ideally, auto-scaling it to fit the graph.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄 So you don't want to show the points for levels 2-5 at all, correct?  Do you want to show the points belonging to group 1, or just the line? And what do you mean by auto-scaling?

Comment: For the first question, yes (I don't want the points for levels 2-5 visible). For the second one, the points and line. The auto-scaling may by done automatically and it is optional, so nevermind with that part.